# Linear Transformations - Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U, V$, and $W$ be finite dimensional vectors spaces over a field.

Suppose that $V\subset U$ is a subspace. Show that there is a subspace $W\subset U$ such that $U=V\oplus W$.

only thing i know about this problem is that you have to use the null space. I'm pretty much lost! any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(v_1, ... ,v_n)$ be a basis for $V$ and extend it to a basis of $U$, which we denote $(v_1, ..., v_n, w_1, ... , w_m)$.  Let $W = \text{span} (w_1, ... , w_m)$.

Now check that $U=V\oplus W$ by showing
$U= V+W$ and $V\cap W = {0}$.

Comment: So U=(v1,...,vn,w1,...,wm)=(v1,...,vn)+(w1,....wm)=V+W right?

How do i show the intersection tho? I have never done that before

Comment: Actually I think I mighta got it.
Suppose that for every u in U there exists a unique vectiors v in V and w in W such that u=v+w. This proves that U=V+W. So let x in V intersect W. Then x=x+0 with x in V and 0 in W, also, x=0+x where 0 in V and x in W. So the expression x=v+w with v in V and w in W is unique by the original assumption and follows that x=0. Therefore VintersectW={0}, which is what we wanted. 
Now suppose U=VdirectsumW. If u in U, then since U=V+W there exists vectors v in V and w in W such that u=v+w.

Comment: If in fact v+w=v'+w', where v,v'in V and w,w'in W. Then v-v'=w'-w. The vector in both V and in W. But assupmption (U=VdirectsumW), then VintersectW ={0} and so v-v'=w'-w=0. Thus, v=v' and w=w', so the vector u as v+w both v in V and w in W is unique.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start with a basis for $V$, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$, and extend it to a basis of $U$, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,u_{k+1},\ldots,u_n\}$. Now find a subspace of $U$ which has the properties that you want by using that extended basis.